# Are there school-management questions that are not off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, closing-questions

From [help for on-topic questions](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions that should not be asked on Martial Arts include:
>
> ...
>
> Business aspects of running a martial arts school (legal advice, retention, location, advertising, etc.) (off-topic)

We currently have the tag [school-management](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-management). There are currently two questions with this tag:

1. [What qualifies a school or business as a legitimate martial arts system?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/681/5961)
   I think this is on-topic, but also not necessarily related to school management.
2. [How effective are different pricing structures for martial arts studios?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/626/5961)
   From help, this is off-topic. How to structure fees is exclusively a business aspect of running a martial arts school.

I propose to close #2, remove the [school-management](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-management) tag from #1, and let [school-management](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-management) disappear. I do not see how you can have a school management tag that is not also [teaching](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) without running into the off-topic business aspects.

Comment: Hmmmm.... good question. Normally #2 would be gone, but in this case it was posted back when the rules were a little looser. I remember a massive purge that happened on Stack Overflow where the old questions that were OT by current standards were deleted by rampaging mobs of torch bearing villagers - I don't know if we're ready for that here yet? (just to be clear, I think #2 is off topic now but was probably on topic back when it was posted).

Comment: @slugster I don't think we need to delete. For some of the old, popular, but off-topic questions, Stack Overflow closed and added a post notice about how questions did not meet the current guidelines and were not a good example of what/how to ask.

Comment: I think definitely close it, and it would be great if we could set up an appropriate close reason that gave us an equally appropriate banner. I followed the meta discussion on SO at the time, it was pretty hard fought and I think they came out with a good compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I support both of your decisions. Every question I can think of that would have `school-management` that would be non-business would basically fall under `teaching` (things like how to teach new people who aren't in the best physical shape, or how to divide "basic" and "advanced" classes).

Answer (score 2):

This is the post notice given when locking a post:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: help center.

I think this captures what we want for #2.